# Method for generating row-column arrays with other arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am attempting to utilize numpy to the best of its capabilities, but I am obviously missing some important link in the documentation due to my 'Noob-ness'.
What I want to do is create an array with a certain number of rows and columns and populate it with a sub array.  The sub array is incremented by a pair of values as one traverses along the row.  For subsequent rows, another pair of values is used to populate the columns.  The best I have come up with is to use list comprehensions to generate the desired output.  At this stage I can create an array which doesn't have the desired shape...I can deal with that in an awkward fashion, so all is not lost.

Here is what I have so far:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=4,threshold=20,edgeitems=3,linewidth=80)   # default print options
>>> sub = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],dtype='float64')   # a sub array of floats
>>> sub
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.]])
>>> e = np.empty((3,4),dtype='object')   # an empty array of the desired shape
>>> e
array([[None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None]], dtype=object)
>>> dX = 1; dY = np.sqrt(3.)/2.0        # values to add to sub array per cell in e
>>> rows,cols = e.shape                 # rows and columns from 'e' shape
>>> out = [sub + [dX*i,dY*(i%2)] for i in range(0,cols)]  # create the first row
>>> for j in range(1,rows):              # create the other rows
...   out += [out[k] + [0,-dY*2*j] for k in range(cols)]    
...   
>>> arr = np.array(out)
>>> arr.shape    # expect to see ((3,4),3,2)...I think
(12, 3, 2)       
>>> arr[0:4]     #  I will let you try this to see the format
```

The last line just shows the format of the first 4 elements of the output array.  What I was hoping to do was populate the empty array, e, in a fashion which is more elegant than my list comprehension method AND/OR how to reshape the array properly.  Again, unless I am missing links in the documentation, I would have expected a 3x4 array containing 3x2 subarrays...which is not what it is showing me.  I would appreciate any help or links to appropriate documentation, since, I have spent hours trolling this site and I am obviously missing some appropriate numpy terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `out` is a list of 4 `(3,2)` arrays.

`np.array(out)` at this stage produces a `(4,3,2)` array.  `np.array` creates the highest dimension array that the data allows.  In this case is concatenates those 4 arrays along a new dimension.

After the `rows` loop, `out` is a list of 12 arrays.  `out +=...` on a list appends them.

So by the same logic, `arr = np.array(out)` will produce a `(12,3,2)` array.  That could be reshaped: `arr = arr.reshape(3,4,3,2)`.

Subarrays from `arr` could be copied to `e`, e.g.:

```
e[0,0] = arr[0,0]
```

Which raises the question, why do you want array like `e`?  What advantage does it have over `arr`?  `arr` represents 'the best of numpy's capabilities`,`e` tries to extend to them in poorly developed areas.

---

Your `out` list can be vectorized with something along this line:

```
ii = np.arange(cols)
ixy = np.array([dX*ii, dY*(ii%2)])
arr1 = sub[None,:,:] + ixy.T[:,None,:]
```

`arr1` is a `(4,3,2)` array, and could be copied to the `e[0,:]` elements.

This could be cleaned up and extended to the other rows.

---

A clean way of iterating over all the elements of `e`, and assigning the corresponding subarray of `arr` uses `np.ndindex` (from the `index_tricks` module):

```
for i in np.ndindex(3,4):
    e[i]=arr[i]
```

While it is a Python level iteration, it does not involve copying data.  It just copies pointers. I'm a little surprised about this, but `e[i,j]` points to the same data block as `arr[i,j]`.  This is evident from the `.__array_interface__` values, and by modifying entries, e.g.

```
e[1,1][0,0] = 30
```

changes the value of `arr[1,1,0,0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  "Which raises the question, why do you want array like e? "  The empty array, e, allows me to leave some of the array entries empty.  The only way to visualize this is to say, that the array is representing real space.  In some places there are objects and in others there is nothing.  I want the capability to do this without extending what I am doing into masked arrays.  I will experiment with your reshape option (3,4,3,2), it never dawned on me that the last 3,2 wasn't enclosed in brackets and I have no idea why I thought 12 would be reshaped as (3,4)

Comment: hpaulj your edit history to your post is interesting, I will have to now come up with the solution to provide the final method to produce the other rows from the first row of arrays

Comment: After playing with the suggestions, it turns out that the method I was using was easiest followed by hpaulj's suggestion of reshaping the array correctly ( in this case from a 12,3,2 to a 3,4,3,2) Then if I wanted part of the row, column axes to have None, I could simply assign is as such using the suggestion of the npindex trick.